# FuelPHP - php oil refine migrate PDO Error

Tags: php, frameworks, migration, fuelphp

I'm trying to setup my **fuelphp** on ubuntu12, nginx in a development environment.
Everything was working for me except when I try to do `php oil refine migrate`.

I was faced with the following error message:

```
Error - invalid data source name in COREPATH/classes/database/pdo/connection.php on line 94
```

**My development/db.php:**

```
return array(
'default' => array(
    'connection'  => array(
        'dsn'        => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=fuel_intro',
        'username'   => 'root',
        'password'   =>  '',
    ),
  ),
);
```

I searched the Internet and fuelphp docs, and still no luck.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual data source name then? (Do an echo in connection.php before line 94.)

Comment: Try changing localhost to 127.0.0.1

Comment: The post below by @bestprogrammerintheworld worked for me, also I installed mysql_connect package. thank you very much for the response.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're doing database configuration incorrectly.  It shouldn't be 'host:localhost', it should be like 'hostname'=>'localhost'. And please use mysql or PDO instead of mysql... (because mysql_* functions are deprecated.

It should be something like:

```
'default' => array(
    'type'           => 'mysqli',
    'connection'     => array(
        'hostname'       => 'localhost',
        'port'           => '3306',
        'database'       => 'fuel_db',
        'username'       => 'your_username',
        'password'       => 'y0uR_p@ssW0rd',
        'persistent'     => false,
        'compress'       => false,
    ),
    'identifier'   => '`',
    'table_prefix'   => '',
    'charset'        => 'utf8',
    'enable_cache'   => true,
    'profiling'      => false,
),
```

Take a look at: 
http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/database/introduction.html for further information.

Comment: Thank you for the post! this worked for me, and also did installed php5-mysql.

Comment: @Rex - ok you'r welcome! If it worked, you should marked this question as solved :-)